# Understand Database host and port?

Tags: python, database, localhost, uri

I'm new to programming. I was trying to set up a database (MangoDB) for school project. The tutorial says:

*The first step when working with PyMongo is to create a MongoClient to the running mongod instance. Doing so is easy:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()

# The above code will connect on the default host and port. We can also specify the host and port explicitly, as follows:

client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
```

Or use the MongoDB URI format:

```
client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
```

How do I understand the concept of "connecting default host and port" and what is the uri thing and why we should use it? Thank you.

Comment: it's M**o**ngo, not M**a**ngo.

Comment: `How do I understand the concept of "connecting default host and port"` For starters, have you tried googling "host and port" ?

Comment: I have googled myself before asking. But I cannot find specific answer to my question. "A network host is a computer or other device connected to a computer network. A network host may offer information resources, services, and applications to users or other nodes on the network. "

Comment: So what do you still not understand?

Comment: I still don't understand why we are using that uri thing and what is the meaning of 'mongodb://localhost:27017/'. I looked that up online too. "a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) is a string of characters used to identify a resource". But can use something else like 'mongodb://localhost:12345/' or even a random string 'uri12345'?

Comment: See my answer then. There isn't really much more to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell `pymongo` where is the database you want it to connect to.

Like many other ORMs/database-connectors `pymongo` uses a connection string. In Mongo's case it starts with `mongodb://` (denoting the schema/protocol, just like `http://` or `ftp://`).

Then comes the host (either a hostname or an IP), which denotes the machine/server on which the database resides, and lastly the port the server listens on.

If the database is on the same machine as the code, you should use `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` as the host.